# Trying to understand why this For Loop has this output

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

So I am working with For Loops as part of my school and I have some code that works but I am struggling to understand *why* it works. It is important for me to really understand why a block of code does what it does - not just that it works.

So a little bit of background. This mini-program utilizes the for loop in order to print a series of `#` characters depending on user input. The idea is that a user enters a number between 1 and 8, and the program will print a `#` character, then move to the next line and print another two, move to the next line and print three etc. and print as many lines as the user inputs.

Input: 5

```
Output:
#
##
###
####
#####
```

The program is here:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

  int rows = 1, height, hash = 1;

  printf("Enter a number between 1-8: ");
  scanf("%i", &height);

  if (height >= 1 || height <= 8) {

    for (rows; rows <= height; rows++) {
      for (hash; hash <= rows; hash++) {
        printf("#");
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I have written the loop down and tried to understand it as follows. If someone could clarify that I have the understanding of how these nested loops are working it would be appreciated:

1. rows = 1; if rows is less than or equal to height (5)
2. run the next for loop
3. hash = 1; if hash is less than or equal to height (5)
4. execute the program statement of this loop (print #)
5. increment the hash variable by 1 making the hash variable = 2
6. go back to the first loop, execute the program statement of this loop 
   (new line)
7. increment the rows variable by 1 - making it 2.
8. repeat

So here is my main question: I'm struggling to see how and *why* the program is able to print more than one `#` using the printf statement when it goes down to a new line. I believe the printf statement is printing two `#` characters due to the `rows` variable contained in the nested for loop.

I am assuming this as when I change the code in the nested for loop to `for (hash; hash == rows; hash++)` then only one `#` character is printed for each line. Same as if I change the code to `for (hash; hash <= rows + 1; hash++)` it will add a `#` character to each line.

Some clarification would be appreciated and help with my school work. I thank you all in advance!

Comment: why `go back to the first loop, execute the program statement of this loop (new line)`? You missing something like `go to 4 if hash <5`.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is `hash` variable. It does not reset to `1` when your inner `for` loop starts again.

Here is correct code:

```
int main(void) {

  int rows = 1, height, hash = 1;

  printf("Enter a number between 1-8: ");
  scanf("%i", &height);

  if (height >= 1 || height <= 8) {

    for (rows; rows <= height; rows++) {
      for (hash = 1; hash <= rows; hash++) {
        printf("#");
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

In your code scope of `hash` is outside of both loops, so in next runs of inner `for` loop, you practically start it with `hash` equal to `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`.

You have set `hash=1;` at start of your code which sets it to `1` when program starts. But you have never reset your `hash` variable after inner loop finishes.

Here is how values change in your code:

```
iteration     row      hash
--------------------------------
1             1        1 -> #
              1        2 -> inner loop end
2             2        2 -> #
              2        3 -> inner loop end
3             3        3 -> #
              3        4 -> inner loop end
4             4        4 -> #
              4        5 -> inner loop end
5             5        5 -> #
              5        6 -> inner loop end
6             6        6 -> outer loop end
```

Comment: @Sam but that is scope of whole program. yes. after program starts, `hash` will be equal to `1`. But what happens after inner loop runs once? hash will be `2` and you never reset it to `1` again.

Answer (score 2):

Variables should be declared in the place where they are used.

It is a reason of various errors when between a variable declaration and its usage there are much code.

The variables  `rows` and `hash` are used only within loops. So they should be declared in these loops. In this case you could avoid the error relative to forgetting to reinitialize the variable `hash` within the inner loop.

If you supposing that the values of a variable should not be negative then declare the variable as having unsigned integer type instead of a signed integer type.

It is unclear why in your program there is used magic number `8`. Why can not the height of the figure be greater than 8?

The program can look the following way.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    while ( 1 )
    {
        const char c = '#';

        unsigned int height;

        printf( "Enter the height of a pyramid (0 - exit): " );

        if ( scanf( "%u", &height ) != 1 || height == 0 ) break;

        putchar( '\n' );

        for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < height; i++ )
        {
            for ( unsigned int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++ )
            {
                putchar( c );
            }
            putchar( '\n' );
        }

        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Enter the height of a pyramid (0 - exit): 1

#

Enter the height of a pyramid (0 - exit): 2

#
##

Enter the height of a pyramid (0 - exit): 3

#
##
###

Enter the height of a pyramid (0 - exit): 4

#
##
###
####

Enter the height of a pyramid (0 - exit): 5

#
##
###
####
#####

Enter the height of a pyramid (0 - exit): 6

#
##
###
####
#####
######

Enter the height of a pyramid (0 - exit): 7

#
##
###
####
#####
######
#######

Enter the height of a pyramid (0 - exit): 8

#
##
###
####
#####
######
#######
########

Enter the height of a pyramid (0 - exit): 9

#
##
###
####
#####
######
#######
########
#########

Enter the height of a pyramid (0 - exit): 10

#
##
###
####
#####
######
#######
########
#########
##########

Enter the height of a pyramid (0 - exit): 0
```

Now let's consider how the program works.

The outer loop

```
while ( 1 )
{
    //...
}
```

is an infinite loop because its condition is never can be equal to 0.

The loop is interrupted when either the user entered an invalid data or when he entered 0.

```
if ( scanf( "%u", &height ) != 1 || height == 0 ) break;
```

Now all is ready to output the pyramid.

This loop

```
    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < height; i++ )
    {
        //...
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
```

in fact is line manager. Try the program by commenting the inner loop and you will see that blank lines will be outputted number of which corresponds to the value of `i + 1`

The inner loop outputs the number of the symbol '#' that corresponds to the value of the expression `i + 1`. That is when i is equal to 0 one symbol '#' is outputted. When i = 1 when two (i + 1) symbols `'#'` are outputted and so on.

So the inner loop outputs a line of `i + 1` symbols `'#'` and the outer loop goes to the next line..

Answer (score 0):

the first argument "rows" in the statement means that you are iterating the rows integer. second statement "rows <= height" means : keep incrementing rows as long as rows less than or equal to height" so when rows is equal to 5, the loop will finish.

For the furst loop, it iterates 5 times as follows:

```
 rows = 1
 rows = 2
 rows = 3
 rows = 4
 rows = 5
```

the second loop prints hashes according to the number of rows. When riws is 1, only one hash is printed. And after each loop, a new line is printed.

Answer (score 0):

The first loop is for the rows and the second loop is for the number of the # s inside the rows.

When you execute  `(hash; hash == rows; hash++)` condition `hash==rows` is only correct once. `for` loop keeps increasing the `hash` value when the value of `hash` and `rows` is equal, it executes the code block.

The second one `(hash; hash <= rows + 1; hash++)`.

Let's trace it. 
First iteration :

`hash` is 1,
`rows` is 1,

```
(1;1<=1+1;hash++)
```

this loop will execute twice, first one because of `1<=1+1` and the second one because of `2<=1+1`